# Связь переменных экземпляра класса с объектом

Tags: java

Правильно ли я понял, что если класс обладает переменной экземпляра (например, int x = 7;), то при создании объекта данного класса данная переменная содержит то значение, определенное в классе.
Например, если мы создадим объект, после чего с помощью ссылки (можно и конструктора) изменим значение переменной (например, на 5), то после создания ещё одного объекта в нем будет содержаться старое значение (то есть 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, вы правильно поняли. Если у вас задано начальное значение 7 для переменной, то каждый новый экземпляр класса будет имень значение переменной 7. Но это значение можно изменять. А можно инициализировать переменную необходимым значением при создании объекта в конструкторе.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.